# Splitting a character in Linux by numbers

Tags: linux

Here I print the file,

```
cat testfile.txt
demo_test_file_2022-06-06
```

i need a output like this

```
demo_test_file_  2022-06-06
```

please help me for splitting the line when numbers present in Linux

thanks in advance

Comment: I think I fixed the formatting of your question to make it more comprehensible.

Comment: I think you should learn how to use `sed` or `awk`.  This question might be helpful:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63707693/sed-insert-whitespace-before-first-number-but-only-if-whitespace-is-not-present

Answer (score 0):

You need to read that file line-by-line into an `std::string` variable, then use [find_first_of](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of) to find the first digit.

Then use [substr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr)